# It is VB.net what I am looking? instead of VBA

Tags: vba, vb.net

I was programing in VBA for a couple of months but sometimes I need some feautures there are not integrated in VBA and I was thinking maybe to **start to programming in VB.net** and use the excel's cells throught VB.net ¿It is possible?

Comment: What sort of functions are you looking at? What are you doing?

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can.  Here is a link to StackOverflow were someone is using VS2010 and excel.  Also a link from microsoft.

[VS2010 and Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546726/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-2010-from-visual-basic-net-2010)

[Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982)

Comment: Correct. VBA is for code within a document, whereas VB.Net runs outside the document, and can manipluate it via the office interop COM libraries.